# Cake PHP email-including links in the email

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I m using cakephp framework. I m trying to send the email in which i want one link which will open a new pop up window. But when i try to click on url it shows url as nojavascript:newPopup(url);
Please help me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=600,width=900,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,
scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:newPopup('<?php echo $this->Html->url(Configure::read('Config.URL'));?>data/CouponOffer/<?php echo $data['CouponCode']['code']; ?>.jpg');">Please print out this coupon to redeem offer.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url){
popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow',(height=600,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,menubar=0,directories=0,status=0));
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:newPopup('<?php echo $this->Html->url(Configure::read('Config.URL'));?>data/CouponOffer/<?php echo $data['CouponCode']['code']; ?>.jpg');">Please print out this coupon to redeem offer.</a>
```